# Excel VBA Add subtotals and remove rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how I can add a row with a sum based on the values of a different column. When I do this, I'd like to remove the rows that added up to that value and retain just one row.

For instance, Column A has PO 10404, PO 10404,PO 10404,PO 10404, PO 10405, PO 10405. I'd like to add a row in between PO 10404 and PO 10405 and then sum the dollar amounts of both PO's (I'm Guessing with a SumIf's) and then delete the individual line and just keep the one line with the total. I would need the contents of the common line, like the PO number.

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: Hi, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't have anything written. I was planning on using a SumIfs statement for the function.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question, but goto

Data>Outline>Subtotal>At Each Change In (Po #)>Use (sum functioN) > Select the dollar amounts column.

Then, collapse the groups, and copy paste values on the subtotals, and delete the grouped rows.

Comment: This is how we are currently doing it. I am looking for something to reduce the redundancy as I have 20 documents with 60-100 rows in each.

Comment: Oh ok, that can be done too. What is the name of the sheets in each of these documents, will the folder always be in the same spot or do you want a file dialog, and where do you want the resulting sum rows to go to?

Comment: the sheets are labeled - pdc adhoc_report-2014november11, but I can add the date manually. I have data in columns 9-14 that I need subtotals on, I'd like the sum rows to go to a new worksheet, and I'd like a file dialog. Thanks

Comment: If this method works currently, I would suggest running a macro recording of performing this method and using that code as a starting base followed up with my save as CSV code in my answer. For example this: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a Pivot Table.  Use "PO#" as your row label and Sum of "Sale Amount" (or whatever that column is called) for the values.

EDIT: Helpful tips for automating this as macro:

> http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=147:create-an-excel-pivot-table-report-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475

Then to automate saving as a CSV:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"c:\MyFile.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: I need to output the final result as a .csv to give to my client. They would accept a pivot table. Thought of that as well. Thanks

Comment: @JosephPrespare Assuming you meant they "won't" accept a pivot table, can't you just copy + paste values from the pivot table and then save that result as a .csv file?