# How to sum values from the same client in one line without pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I made a code that prompts the user to select a file and import it to a sheet.

Then, I have to put this sheet in a pattern to export it to use on my company's software. If the file is not in the pattern, the software won't import my file.

The company's software does not allow the file to have repeated clients. So, I need to sum the values from the column VALOR by the CPF of the client. So I get no repeated client and the file says the ammount that the client payed.

I tried doing with a pivot table, but since my code imports the file to the sheet automatically, I had problems with dealing with the pivot table.

Is there another way?

Comment: Typically, it makes it easier to provide solutions if you share your code and where within the code you are having issues specifically.

Comment: Also your issue seems awfully familiar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050165/excel-vba-add-subtotals-and-remove-rows/27050432?noredirect=1#comment42646154_27050432

Comment: I'd reconsider the pivot table. It's possible to import all kinds of data into one. Have you tried the Data menu options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your code to bring in the data into a sheet, use http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=147:create-an-excel-pivot-table-report-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475 for code on creating a macro to automate creating a pivot table.  Then you can `.copy` and `.pastespecial xlValues` the pivottable data into your final sheet to get it out of the pivot table format.  After that just save in whatever format you need (can also be in the macro).

Answer (score 0):

Can you include `sumif` formulas in your VBA code? If so you create a new worksheet with the unique CFPs and then have the `sumif` formulas there, and that tab will be the one you upload to your system (whether in that same file or a standalone file)

Comment: how would be my sumif?

Comment: The `CPF` column would be the criteria range, your first unique CPF (say, `CPF1`) would be the criteria, and then the sum range would be the `VALOR` column